# query for non-entity types in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-4, ado.net

i'm trying to query for non-entity object in my database 
...i found that i should use sqlQuery(query,parameters); in msdn and a lot of blogs,
but the problem is when i use thee following code

```
 db.USERS.SqlQuery<string>(query, mail).ToList<string>();
```

i get the following syntax error " The non-generic method 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet.SqlQuery(string, params object[])' cannot be used with type arguments"
is there any specific name spaces that i should use or what ?

Comment: if i recall correctly, use `db.Database.SqlQuery()...`

Comment: @Jonesy's right. `db.USERS.SqlQuery` is not generic because it's already constrained to one type (User).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx) recommends we use the table `DbSet` to invoke `SqlQuery` to return entity-types, like e.g. here:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("dbo.GetBlogs").ToList(); 
}
```

The above will automatically cast the result to a `Blog` entity.

In your case, you want the result cast to a string, a non-entity type, so you'll need to use the generic form of `SqlQuery` which is found in the `Database` object in the context:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogNames = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>( 
                       "SELECT Name FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); 
}
```

Read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx)  if you need more details